How to disable browser update/save password prompt on error?
In case of invalid user credentials, how can I tell browser that it should not attempt to save invalid user password (don't show prompt)?
Browser "chrome".


Don't read this, data to fill characters requirement to post a question. Don't read this, data to fill characters requirement to post a question. Don't read this, data to fill characters requirement to post a question. Don't read this, data to fill characters requirement to post a question.
